# get ordered DiGraph edges

Tags: networkx

here is my directed network, that I want to plot. 
[Plot of DiGraph Network with colored edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgyDF.png)
The edges take their specific color from a colormap. The colormap is linked to every edge temperature. 
So for :

edge number :13 temperature is: 14 °C → edge color should be blue but is red

edge number :14 temperature is: 38 °C → edge color should be red but is blue

The problem is, that I don't get a consistened order of the edges or edge color. Id don't know if the edges or the colers are unordered.

The problem is already described in:
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/classes/ordered.html
I'am using Python 3.7. Either nx.DiGraph() or nx.OrderedDiGraph() doesn't get the right order. There is not really an answer, how to prevent networkx from mixing the order of edges.
Can someone pleease help me? :)

Here is my code ready to compile:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# nodes input
nodes_id = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
nodes_x_y = [(1, 1.0), (2, 1.0), (3, 1.0), (4, 1.0), (5, 1.0), (2, 1.5), (3, 1.5), (4, 1.5),
             (5, 1.5), (2, 2.0), (3, 2.0), (4, 2.0), (5, 2.0), (2, 2.5), (3, 2.5), (4, 2.5),
             (5, 2.5), (1, 3.0), (2, 3.0), (3, 3.0), (4, 3.0), (5, 3.0)]
# edges input         those should match together↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ those should match together
# edge labels
edges_id =      [0,     1,     2,    3,    4,    5,   6,    7,    8,    9,    10,   11,   12,   13,   14,    15,  16,   17,   18,   19,   20,   21,   22,    23]
# edge temperatures
edges_tp_forw = [35.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 24.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 24.0, 14.0, 38.0, 33.0, 24.0, 14.0, 38.0, 33.0, 40.0, 14.0, 38.0, 33.0, 40.0, 40.0, 38.0, 33.0]
#                     those should match together↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ those should match together
edges_u = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 5, 10, 7, 12, 9, 14, 11, 16, 13, 19, 15, 21, 18, 19, 20, 20]
edges_v = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 9, 6, 11, 8, 13, 10, 15, 12, 18, 14, 20, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21]
# graph
G = nx.OrderedDiGraph()
# or: G = nx.DiGraph()
# Add network nodes
for k in nodes_id:
    G.add_node(nodes_id[k], pos=nodes_x_y[k])
# Add network edges
for k in edges_id:
    G.add_edge(edges_u[k], edges_v[k], edge_color=edges_tp_forw[k], name=edges_id[k], labels=edges_id[k])
# position
pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos')
# open plot
f = plt.figure()
plt.axis('off')
# draw nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, node_size=00, node_shape='o', node_color='grey', font_weight='bold')
# draw node labels
bbox = dict(facecolor='grey',  edgecolor='grey', boxstyle='circle')
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, dict(enumerate(nodes_x_y)), bbox=bbox, font_size=6)
# draw edges
max_value = max(edges_tp_forw)
# Heatmap color map
edge_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
# draw edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=1, edge_color=edges_tp_forw, edge_cmap=edge_cmap, arrows=True)
# draw edge labels
edges_id = tuple(edges_id)
edges = tuple(zip(edges_u, edges_v))
edges_labels_id_tp = [pair for pair in zip(edges_id, edges_tp_forw)]
edges_draw_labels = dict(zip(edges, [elem for elem in edges_labels_id_tp]))
bbox = dict(facecolor='white', edgecolor='grey', boxstyle='round')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edges_draw_labels,     bbox=bbox, font_size=6, rotate=False)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specifications are totally fine. This seems to be a bug in the current version of networkx. I would raise an issue on their github.

As a workaround, you could use my fork of their drawing utilities, [netgraph](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph). 
I enforce the use of dictionaries for specifying node and edge attributes (if you want them to differ across nodes/edges) to prevent exactly this problem.

[image]

```
import netgraph # install with: pip install netgraph
from matplotlib import colors, cm

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# your specifications

nodes_id = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
nodes_x_y = [(1, 1.0), (2, 1.0), (3, 1.0), (4, 1.0), (5, 1.0), (2, 1.5), (3, 1.5), (4, 1.5),
             (5, 1.5), (2, 2.0), (3, 2.0), (4, 2.0), (5, 2.0), (2, 2.5), (3, 2.5), (4, 2.5),
             (5, 2.5), (1, 3.0), (2, 3.0), (3, 3.0), (4, 3.0), (5, 3.0)]
# edges input         those should match together↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ those should match together
# edge labels
edges_id =      [0,     1,     2,    3,    4,    5,   6,    7,    8,    9,    10,   11,   12,   13,   14,    15,  16,   17,   18,   19,   20,   21,   22,    23]
# edge temperatures
edges_tp_forw = [35.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 24.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 24.0, 14.0, 38.0, 33.0, 24.0, 14.0, 38.0, 33.0, 40.0, 14.0, 38.0, 33.0, 40.0, 40.0, 38.0, 33.0]
#                     those should match together↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ those should match together
edges_u = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 8, 5, 10, 7, 12, 9, 14, 11, 16, 13, 19, 15, 21, 18, 19, 20, 20]
edges_v = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 9, 6, 11, 8, 13, 10, 15, 12, 18, 14, 20, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21]
edges_labels_id_tp = [pair for pair in zip(edges_id, edges_tp_forw)]

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# conversion of your specifications to dictionaries

edges = list(zip(edges_u, edges_v))
node_positions = dict(zip(nodes_id, nodes_x_y))
node_labels = {node : str(node) for node in nodes_id}
color_map = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=min(edges_tp_forw),
                                                     vmax=max(edges_tp_forw)),
                               cmap=plt.get_cmap('coolwarm'))
edge_color = {edge : color_map.to_rgba(val) for edge, val in zip(edges, edges_tp_forw)}
edge_labels = {edge : str(pair) for edge, pair in zip(edges, edges_labels_id_tp)}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10,5))
netgraph.draw(edges,
              node_positions       = node_positions,
              node_edge_width      = 0.,
              node_color           = 'lightgray',
              node_labels          = node_labels,
              node_label_font_size = 6,
              edge_color           = edge_color,
              edge_labels          = edge_labels,
              edge_label_font_size = 6,
              rotate               = False,
              draw_arrows          = True,
              ax                   = ax)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can't believe that this is a bug. Your netgraph solution works fine! :) 
Is there an option to change the size of the arrows? And can I force a gap between arrow and node? That would makes it perfect.

Comment: Glad you like my little project. You can make the edges thicker by increasing the `edge_width` (default is 1.). I am letting matplotlib calculate the offsets between nodes and arrows, so forcing a gap between the arrow and edge is a bit trickier. But it can be done by setting the `node_edge_width` to some non-zero value and setting the `node_edge_alpha` to zero (i.e. making the node edge thick but invisible). If you have any further questions or feedback on netgraph, then I would appreciate it if you would raise an issue on the [github](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph).

Comment: Regarding `networkx`, they somewhat recently switched to a new internal graph representation, which made things faster but also introduced a bunch of bugs. I expect they will iron out most of these in the next couple of minor versions. However, they do not like breaking backwards compatibility. That is a good thing most of the time but in this case, it also means that their old, and hence less than polished plotting API will remain a bit clunky and have weird behaviours.

Comment: Just updated networkx to 2.3. Update is from May 13, but the weighted color of the edges is still unordered. ?? I tried DiGraph() and OrderedDiGraph(). Definitely runs faster then with 2.2...

Comment: What are you using to plot now? If you are using `netgraph`, and it's not working in the way that you are expecting it to work, then post an issue on [my github](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph). Otherwise, you should think about raising an issue on the `networkx` github.